# breakup large text file with beginning row

Tags: python

I need to break up a 1.3m text file to smaller text file based on the 1st row of a section.    The data inputs will likely vary over time so I'd like to automate the process with a something that looks like, but open to any suggestions:

FirstLine test1
1   1   1
TIMESTEP    Avg VARIANCE(mm^2)  STD
2006-01-06T00:00:00Z    77.556335   114.23446   10.688052
2006-02-06T00:00:00Z    30.174097   20.363855   4.512633
2006-03-06T00:00:00Z    65.48971    146.99098   12.123984
2006-04-06T00:00:00Z    68.65635    335.42905   18.314722
2006-05-06T00:00:00Z    65.31086    121.24954   11.011337
2006-06-06T00:00:00Z    123.571075  172.97223   13.151891
FirstLine test2
1   1   1
TIMESTEP    Avg VARIANCE(mm^2)  STD
2006-01-06T00:00:00Z    66.34833    258.47723   16.077227
2006-02-06T00:00:00Z    16.08292    16.153652   4.0191607
2006-03-06T00:00:00Z    34.585014   185.23705   13.610182
I need the 1st row to be the FirstLine row, and all to the next row with FirstLine.

I've tried identifying the row number with this script:

```
    def search_string_in_file(content, FirstLine):
        line_number = 0
        list_of_results = []
        RowList = []
        # Open the file in read only mode

        with open('test.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
            # Read all lines in the file one by one
            for line in read_obj:
                # For each line, check if line contains the string
                 line_number += 1
                 if FirstLine in line:
                     # If yes, then add the line number & line as a tuple in the list
                    list_of_results.append((line_number, line.rstrip()))
                    print(list_of_results)
            # Return list of tuples containing line numbers and lines where string is found
        RowList = pd.DataFrame.from_string(list_of_results)
        return list_of_results
```

The above seems to run successfully, but there are no results and no errors.

Comment: Can you add an example of the expected result?

Comment: In the example data in the post there are 2 sections, the 1st file would be from the line with "FirstLine test1" and the 2nd would be "FirstLine test2".  The row counts can vary so I was hoping to write the row numbers for the "FirstLine" rows to a tibble and use those to exact the correct rows to a new file.

Comment: could u compare it as `FirstLine.lower() in line.lower()`?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this that actually cut some steps out.

```
found = re.findall(r'\n*(.*?\n\#)\n*', data, re.M | re.S)
```